# Nativescript Prettify Code using google-code-prettify or any other plugin

Tags: typescript, nativescript

I am trying to display code in my application. I tried using HtmlView and google-code-prettify but I am not able import js files within my code. I am also not sure if it supports Nativescript as the documents talk nothing about it. Following is relevant code samples:

**home-page.xml**

```xml
<Page loaded="pageLoaded" class="page" xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">

    <ActionBar title="Home" class="action-bar">
    </ActionBar>

    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout class="home-panel">
            <HtmlView html="{{ htmlString }}" />            
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</Page>
```

**home-view-model.ts**

```js
import { Observable } from 'tns-core-modules/data/observable';

export class HomeViewModel extends Observable {
    htmlString: string = "<pre class=\"prettyprint\"><br/>" +
        "List<MyOrderItemModel> myOrderItemModelList = new ArrayList&lt;&gt;();" +
        "<br/>" +
        "myOrderItemModelList.add(new MyOrderItemModel(R.drawable.tide_prod, 2, \"Tide Detergent\", \"149.50\", \"Ren's Grocery\", \"Juan Dela cruz\", \"Order_Received\", 4, 3));<br/>" +
        "<br/>" +
        "if (myOrderItemModelList.contains(\"Delivered\")) {<br/>" +
        "    MyOrderItemOnProcessAdapter myOrderItemOnProcessAdapter = new MyOrderItemOnProcessAdapter(myOrderItemModelList);<br/>" +
        "    my_orders_recyclerview.setAdapter(myOrderItemOnProcessAdapter);<br/>" +
        "    myOrderItemOnProcessAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();<br/>" +
        "}<br/>" +
        "  </pre>";

    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

I have also created a sample playground example https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=uGaqc3&v=5.

Does anyone know any way to prettify code in Nativescript?

Comment: Have you tried a `WebView` ?

Comment: HtmlView supports only very limited tags / styles.

Comment: No but i guess it is used to display webpage within your app. Not sure how can I use it to show my custom code?

Comment: I understand that but how can any existing plugin be used to beautify the code?

Comment: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=uGaqc3&v=5

Comment: Thank you Nick but It is the same link which I mentioned.

Comment: You can use WebView to show html string, it necessarily need not to be a HTML page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **WebView** instead, HtmlView support only very limited tags / styles.

**XML**

```
<WebView src="{{ htmlString }}" />
```

**JS**

```
htmlString: string = "<script src=\"./code-prettify/loader/run_prettify.js\"></script>" +
        "<pre class =\"prettyprint\"><br/>" +
        "List<MyOrderItemModel> myOrderItemModelList = new ArrayList&lt;&gt;();" +
        "<br/>" +
        "myOrderItemModelList.add(new MyOrderItemModel(R.drawable.tide_prod, 2, \"Tide Detergent\", \"149.50\", \"Ren's Grocery\", \"Juan Dela cruz\", \"Order_Received\", 4, 3));<br/>" +
        "<br/>" +
        "if (myOrderItemModelList.contains(\"Delivered\")) {<br/>" +
        "    MyOrderItemOnProcessAdapter myOrderItemOnProcessAdapter = new MyOrderItemOnProcessAdapter(myOrderItemModelList);<br/>" +
        "    my_orders_recyclerview.setAdapter(myOrderItemOnProcessAdapter);<br/>" +
        "    myOrderItemOnProcessAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();<br/>" +
        "}<br/>" +
        "  </pre>";
```

[Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=uGaqc3&v=7)

Comment: Thank you for your response. This doesn't really prettify the code.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by pretify, all it was expected to do, honor spacing and line breaks. If you want to pretify, use pretify libraries.

Comment: By prettify, I mean give different colors to keywords similar to how StackOverflow does to the code. I have added the google-code-prettify library but couldnt figure out how to import them inside Nativescript.

Comment: It should be straight forward, just include the library in the html string.

Comment: Thank you for the information Manoj. We are somewhat close. The code coloring doesn't work when the script is imported from pluginas shown in your typesript example but works when used the script <script src=\"https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js\"></script>

Comment: The Playground works I already verified it. If it doesn't work with your local machine that's your webpack you have to deal with. Of course you can use remote JS file from CDN if you are comfortable running it with internet

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned earlier that it doesnt work on ios and i didn't check android yet.

Comment: Again for iOS it's security issue, you can load scripts only from the same location as your HTML file is, either you will have to copy the scripts to documents directory and write HTML files to disk then load it in Webview or override the default settings natively to load the scripts into WKWebView configuration.